There is a linear function inbetween a concave function and a convex function
Let $X$ be a linear space over $\mathbb{R}$. Show that for $h, g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \,\cup \{\infty\}$, convex functions such that $h^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is an absorbing set and $0 \in g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, there exists a linear functional $f \in X^*$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $-g \leq f + \gamma \leq h$.
In our lectures, we have proven the following:

$p_g(x):=\inf \{\frac{1}{\alpha}g(\alpha x) \,| \, \alpha > 0 \}$ is a sublinear function when $g$ is convex, $g(0) \geq 0$, and $g^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is absorbing.

For a sublinear function $p$ and a convex function $g$ with $-g \leq p$ and $g \neq \infty$, the set $\{f \in X^* \, | \, \exists \gamma \in \mathbb{R}: -g \leq f + \gamma \leq p \}$ is not empty (a sublinear function takes only finite values.


My approach was to use both of these statements. However, I'm struggling to show that $-g(x) \leq p_h(x)$.
Could you provide a hint on how to prove this inequality?

@copper.hat In our definition, a function is allowed to take infinite values. I forgot to specify this
